# Unix command to parse string

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to figure out a command to parse the following file content:

```
Operation=GET
Type=HOME
Counters=CacheHit=0,Exception=1,Validated=0
```

I need to extract `Exception=1` into its own line. I'm fiddling with awk, sed and grep but not making much progress. Does anyone have any tips on using any unix command to perform this?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve your problem. Check with `man grep` and see if your `grep` includes the `-o` option. Good luck.

Comment: This makes little sense.  If you want "Exception=1" on a line, write `echo Exception=1`.  Are you trying to get the 2nd column of a comma delimited line?  Do you want to get the value from all lines that have 2 commas?  Or are you looking for any string of the form `*=1`?  Or are you looking for any string of the form `Exception=X`?  Or are you looking for the clause that precedes "Validated"?  Or are you looking for the string after "CacheHit=0"?  Or perhaps you care about something else entirely.  You need to describe how you want to filter the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do this. Here is one assuming the file is called "file.txt". Grab the line you want, replace everything from the start of the line up to Except with just `Except`, then pull out the first field using comma as the delimiter.

```
$ grep Exception file.txt | sed 's/.*Except/Except/g' | cut -d, -f 1
Exception=1
```

If you wanted to use gawk:

```
$ grep Exception file.txt | sed 's/.*Except/Except/g' | gawk -F, '{print $1}'
Exception=1
```

or just using grep and sed:

```
$ grep Exception file.txt | sed 's/.*\(Exception=[0-9]*\).*/\1/g'
Exception=1
```

or as @sheltter reminded me:

```
$ egrep -o "Exception=[0-9]+" file.txt
Exception=1
```

Comment: You should stay with the one command solution.  Mixing grep,sed,awk are seldom needed.  Also quote the grep expression.  `egrep -o "Exception=[0-9]+" file`

Comment: can't upvote an answer with quoting issues (or using 2 cmds when one will do, for that matter). Keep posting and good luck. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since your file is close to bash syntax, there is a fun little trick you can do to make bash itself parse the file. First, use some program like tr to transform the input into a something bash can parse, and then "source" that, which will create shell variables you can expand later to get the values.

```
source <(tr , $'\n' < file_name_goes_here)
echo $Exception
```

Comment: Did like this.  You can then just change echo to any field name to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a mix of commands.

```
awk -F, 'NR==2 {print RS$1}' RS="Exception"  file
Exception=1
```

Here we split the line by the keyword we look for `RS="Exception"`
If the line has two record (only when keyword is found), then 
print first field, separated using command, with Record selector.

PS This only works if you have one `Exception` field